# Windows 10 not caching credentials

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I recently upgraded my server to Windows Server 2012 R2, and I relied heavily on domain credential caching on my laptop and now it isn't letting me log into my laptop when not on the network. The group policy is set to allow 10 cached logins and is set to not require the domain controller to unlock.

What would be causing me not to be able to log in offline?

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, it turns out it has to do with the user account. I created another account and it worked.